# IllegalAccessError when calling ant script from maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, jsp, maven-2, ant, build-process

I just updated Maven from 2.0.9 to 2.2.1 and I'm getting the following exception when running a maven build:

```
INFO] [antrun:run {execution: precompile-jsp}]
[INFO] Executing tasks

default:

jspc:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\builds\trunk\webapps\vyre_portlets\WEB-INF\jsp_src
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\unify\trunk\portlets\build-jsps.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\unify\trunk\portlets\build-jsps.xml:7: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator.decodeUri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; from class org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader
```

The build-jsps.xml ant script runs the org.apache.jasper.JspC task to precompile JSP in the a webapp that maven is building. This was working fine with Maven 2.0.9.

Google gives a bunch of people asking similar questions, but no answers. Has anyone run into this and knows how to resolve this? Or even just why I'm getting the IllegalAccessError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to set ANT dependency for "maven-antrun-plugin" explicitly.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        .... 
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
               <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
               <version>1.7.0</version>                                   
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Note that there are multiple places where you can find ANT in Maven's public repository:

1. `<groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>`
2. `<groupId>ant</groupId>`

(2) is the old one so use (1) instead

Comment: Eureka! I've found out why this wasn't working for me. The ant call that failed was in a subproject of a project that also does ant calls. It appears maven only sets up the dependencies for a plugin once per execution, so you have to do it in the first usage in the build.

Comment: Do I  have to change each POM for each project that I have?

Comment: @UmReeta: if you have multi-module POM structure then I believe you can do only in "parent" POM

Answer (score 0):

In Maven 2.2.x, the versions of many of the plugins have been updated, if you run the build with -X, you'll see what version of the antrun-plugin has been used. If these are different versions, it may be using a different version of org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator. Looking at the change history for Locator, the decodeUri method was introduced in Ant 1.7 and has been tweaked a few times, though nothing that would obvioulsy cause the problem.

Can you post a minimal pom and ant configuration that shows the error? this would help diagnose the problem.